# undefined method `product_bids_path'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I following this [tutorial](https://shauntm.com/notes/entries/179), 
when I want to show my product, i'm getting this error:

```
undefined method `product_bids_path'
```

in my routes file:

```
  devise_for :users
  resources :products do
    resources :auctions, only: [:create] do
      resources :bids, only: [:create]
    end
  end
```

in `products/show.html.erb`

```
=render "auction"
=render "bid"
```

here is my bid partial:

```
= form_for [ @product, @product.auction, Bid.new] do |f|
```

Here in this `form_for` helper its need to send  `product_auction_bids_path` url request but its sending `product_bids_path` url request.

How should i write my correct `form_for` helper that send request to  `product_auction_bids_path`

Comment: What is the relation between product and auction?

Comment: product has_one :auction

Comment: Seems like `@product.auction` is nil. Try to debug it.

Comment: yes. first we show product then user create auction

Comment: So `@product.auction` is nil?

Comment: That is why the error.

Comment: @Pavan how can I avoid this?

Comment: Just make sure `@product.auction` is not nil.

Comment: thanks, :) got my answer
`-if @product.has_auction?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the comments solved it;

For the benefit of readers, if you have a nested set of routes (as follows), you have to make sure you call the path with *all* the dependent objects:

```
resources :products do
    resources :auctions, only: [:create] do
      resources :bids, only: [:create]
    end
end

products_auctions_bids_path(@product, @auction, @bid)
```

---

Now.

There's an important point to be made about this -- the [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#limits-to-nesting) state that you should not nest routes beyond more than one level:

> Resources should never be nested more than 1 level deep.

You really need to make sure you are able to call a route based on less unique information than the `primary key`'s of all three nested resources.

I know you're not calling the individual paths (only `create`), but it's still a bad pattern to nest it all like you're doing.

There are several ways to remedy it; I would personally just use `auction` and `bid`:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :auctions, only: :create do
   resources :bids
end
```

`Auctions` should be unique based on their primary key anyway...

```
#app/models/auction.rb
class Auction < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :auction
   has_many :bids
end

#app/models/bid.rb
class Bid < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :auction
end
```

This will allow you to identify the auction specifically, and then create bids as you require.